# ошибка перезапуска nginx ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

на Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS пытаюсь перезапустить сервис NGINX (systemctl restart nginx.service) получаю ошибку:

> Failed to add a watch for /run/systemd/ask-password: inotify watch
> limit reached

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13751/110559

Comment: перезапусти с судо

Comment: @eri, ошибка в таком случае, по идее, другая.